# Moving point after moving polygone in POSTGIS/PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers, geometry, postgis

I want to write a trigger for updating the geometry of a point after changing the geometry of an area in another table.

I got two tables in the same schema:

Tab1: id, geom(point), linkedname

Tab2: id, geom(polygone), linkedname

The point should jump always in the Center of the moved polygone with the same linkedname after updating the table.

Any ideas? I'm using PostgreSQL12.3 with POSTGIS3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a second table at all?

Just use a generated column. It will update whenever you change the polygon.

```
    create table tab2(
id serial primary key,
    geom geometry(polygon),
    linkedname text,
centroid geometry(point) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (st_centroid(geom)) stored
);
```

EDIT

You can also use a view rather than a second table. A view behaves just like a table, so you can link it into your client. This will by definition always be up to date and you don't have to worry about triggers.

```
create view tab1 as
select id, linkedname, st_centroid(geom) as geom 
from tab2;
```